# SQLSRV Query to return all products listed under a column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Here is my code

```
if (isset($_GET["range"])) { $range = $_GET["range"]; } else { $range = BLOB; }
```

Basically, I'm using the GET variable to search a table under the column 'range'. Only problem is, in the case that range is not set I would like a default variable that could return all the products.

I'm doing this so I can avoid including multiple SQL queries. Mind you, the part of the code I'm trying to replace is BLOB. Any thoughts?

EDIT: If you're going to vote down my question, at least have the decency to comment why.

Comment: You better sanitize your range. It depends where it is in your query, but if it's after `range = ` then replacing BLOB with `'0 OR 1'` will select all rows from your table.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. Just to let you know, range represents a 'clothing range', this is a e-commerce website.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking 'I have a place where I put a piece of data to use as a filter (the name of a clothing range) to limit the returns on my search. If I don't pick a specific clothing range, what can I put in that filter?'

SQL has a data value to indicate 'I have no meaningful data in this field': NULL.

You have no meaningful information on what clothing range you would like to filter on, so one possible method for handling this would be to pass in a NULL for range, and then have the SQL side process that parameter with a `range_variable = range_column OR range_variable IS NULL`

Here's a quick and dirty example so you can see how it works:

```
create table clothing (range varchar (20))

insert into clothing    
select 'Value1'
union select 'value2'
union select 'value3'

select * from clothing


declare @range_var varchar(20)

set @range_var = 'value2'

select * from clothing 
where range = @range_var or @range_var is null

set @range_var = NULL

select * from clothing 
where range = @range_var or @range_var is null


GO
drop table clothing
```

Comment: Though NULL would return nothing. I want the opposite of that, I want to return everything

Comment: If the value in the range column were null, yes. This looks at your range_variable that you're passing into SQL and if it's null, return everything. I'll attach an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment, but I can't, because of my reputation, so I'll try to answer the question as I understand it.

If your query ends with something like (no matter the correct syntax) :

```
LIMIT 0, $range
```

Try something like

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['range']) && is_int($_GET['range']))
    $range = ' LIMIT 0, '.$_GET['range'];
else
    $range = '';
```

Or in just one line

```
<?php
$range = (isset($_GET['range']) && is_int($_GET['range'])) ? ' LIMIT 0, '.$_GET['range'] : '';
```

I hope I'm not off base...

Comment: The LIMIT clause is not sqlsrv syntax. Also, range represents a range of products (men, women, unisex, etc...). I'm looking for code that will return any range if it is not set